# mediawiki default category in category

Tags: mediawiki, categories

I use a MediaWiki and extension `CategoryTree`.

Problem occurs if I want to create a new page. I chose a category but my category list is empty: [image: screenshot] When I create a new one and add it I see a new category in `Mediawiki`, but when I create a new page my category list is empty again.

How can I predefine a category? Is that possible? I use the latest version of `MediaWiki`.

Comment: CategoryTree seems unrelated to the question - it just changes how category pages are displayed. It seems like you are using the [WYSIWYG](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WYSIWYG) extension for editing categories, which is more relevant.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to put a certain category into the source text of every new page, there are easy ways to create an edit link that does that. Is that the kind of thing you have in mind?